# php html. How show users stored db value in <option>?

Tags: php

This will be shown on the user settings page.

(example)

```
       <select>
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>

       </select>
```

If the user has value 3 stored in the db then i want the option-dropdown to show value 3 when the user is on the settings page.
How can i do that?

Comment: `count()` - `num_rows()` - conditional statement *etc.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get that value from the database. I'll use MySQLi in this example.

```
<?php
    // Connecting to the database
    $mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_dbname);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");

    // Getting the row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $valueFromDB = $row['columName'];
    }
?>

<select>
    <option value="0" <?php if ($valueFromDB == "0") {echo " selected";} ?>>0</option>
    <option value="1" <?php if ($valueFromDB == "1") {echo " selected";} ?>>1</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if ($valueFromDB == "2") {echo " selected";} ?>>2</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if ($valueFromDB == "3") {echo " selected";} ?>>3</option>
    <option value="4" <?php if ($valueFromDB == "4") {echo " selected";} ?>>4</option>
</select>
```

This is a series of if-statements. There are probably other was of going around this, but this will work.

**EDIT**: As you commented, this is a lot of work if you have many lines of options. If that's the case, you can use the following code to make PHP generate them.

```
<select>
    <?php 
    $numRows = 30; // This is the number of options values you output
    for ($i=0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
        echo "<option value=\"$i\"";
        if ($valueFromDB == "$i") 
            echo " selected"; 
        echo ">$i</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

This will output options equal to the value of `$numRows`. Note that it starts counting at 0.

Comment: I could probably get that to work but its not the best way if you have hundreds of values to choose from :/

Comment: I will probably use this becasue its a easy way. Thanks :D

Comment: I'm on mobile at the moment, I'll post a solution for that later tonight when I'm home.

Comment: Please see my comment for an updated answer. If you found my answer helpful, don't forget to upvote and check it as your solution, please :) If you have any more comments, don't hesitate asking - I'll gladly see if I can help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use "selected" attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

If you are looping data and generating html from PHP, do something like this:

```
foreach($your_array as $info){

    $add = NULL;
    if($info['is_selected'] == 1){
        $add = 'selected="selected"';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$info['id'].'" '.$add.'>'.$info['name'].'</option>';

}
```

Comment: Im very new to php. I cant get that to work :/ is it possibly to use another loop? Might be easier for me maybe.

Comment: This isn't a complicated loop. Foreach will seek each index in $your_array and store it at $info variable. it's the same as for($i=0;$i<=count($your_array;$i++). Check it out: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php